# Using JavaSparkContext's addFile method fails when path has a space

Tags: apache-spark

I use Spark 1.4.0 with Hadoop 2.4.0 and attempt to invoke the addFile method where the input string has a space at position x+1. I get an error at position x. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
Java exception occurred:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index x: /some/path/where/position x+1 is a space character
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1316)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.addFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:671)
```

Edit: Code snippet and reference

```
    SparkConf sconf= new SparkConf();
    sconf.setMaster(somename);
    sconf.setAppName(someappname);

    JavaSparkContext jsconf= new JavaSparkContext(sconf);
    jsconf.addFile(dataFile); // dataFile is a String object with contents "/some/path/where/position x+1 is a space character"
```

addFile reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#addFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: could you put a snippet of the code causing the problem?

Comment: Since it is URI ...can you add %20 instead of space and see if it works?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your replies. I tried %20 and it doesn't work: I get "Added File .. does not exist". It seems like the % is replaced as %25, so the space in my string gets read as %2520

Comment: Try replacing the space with a `+` sign

Comment: where is your file you are trying to add. is it hdfs or local file?

Comment: It is a local file (not on hdfs) on a network location. `//myNetworkFolder/some/path/where/position x+1 is a space character`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
jsconf.addFile(java.net.URLEncoder.encode(dataFile));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you meant to use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode` method and I get an error of "Added File ... does not exist".